# Infinite Scroll iFrame Troubleshooting - Tumblr

Tags: iframe, tumblr, infinite-scroll

I am trying to embed an infinite scroll content page within an iframe on the Tumblr I am working on:

Page with iFrame: http://boffoheartlike.tumblr.com/artist/brad-troemel

iFrame Content: http://boffoheartlike.tumblr.com/tagged/Brad-Troemel

The problem I'm having is I cannot get all the content to load with infinite scroll within the iframe. If you look at the "Page with iFrame," only half the posts load here.

Is there a way to call the Infinite Scroll .js on this page to load all its posts?

Thanks,
KF

Comment: Have you looked at `retrieve`: https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll